# My code isn't running after I break a while loop even though there is code after it

Tags: python-3.x

I tried making a rock-paper-scissors game, and to make sure that the user entered a number, I made a while loop. But after the user entered a number, the loop breaks but it won't keep running the game itself after it. How do I fix this?

```
main_choice = input('Please enter the number that matches your choice:\n')
#Make sure that user enters a number
while True:
    try:
        int(main_choice)
        break
    except:
        main_choice = input('Please enter a NUMBER:\n')
        continue



#Play
if main_choice == 1:
    play_game()
```

Comment: you want : `main_choice = int(main_choice)` as the cast to `int()` is not "in-place"

Comment: `if int(main_choice) == 1:`  would do it;  I would probably suggest using isnumeric as well as what if they enter in a letter?.......

Answer (score 0):

I see others have placed the answer in the comments... but I'll place the full example in here. You need to convert your input into an integer to be able to compare it (or the 1 into a str).

**The line that needs to change:**

> `if main_choice == 1:`

**Change to:**

> `if int(main_choice) == 1:`

```
main_choice = input('Please enter the number that matches your choice:\n')

#Make sure that user enters a number
while True:
    try:
        int(main_choice)
        break
    except:
        main_choice = input('Please enter a NUMBER:\n')
        continue
#Play
if int(main_choice) == 1:
    print("Game is now being played")
```

**Gives the output:**

```
Please enter the number that matches your choice:
1
Game is now being played
```